# .NET Maui Top Navigation bar not centered in IOS and Android

Tags: c#, .net, maui

I need to have one bottom nav bar and a top nav bar, the bottom navigation bar appears with the items centered but the top navigation bar is always aligned left

[top bar not centered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6dM3.png)

I have tried centering but only worked for android and the iOS app wasn't starting

Comment: You said you tried centering, please add relevant sample code to your post which will help reproduce your issue.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, you want to align the three upper tabs evenly. You can create platform-specific implementation file `CustomShellRenderer.cs` repectively.

For **Android**:

Create the class: CustomShellRenderer.cs under **Platform/Android**:

```
public class CustomShellRenderer : ShellRenderer
{
 
    public CustomShellRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {

    }

    protected override IShellTabLayoutAppearanceTracker CreateTabLayoutAppearanceTracker(ShellSection shellSection)
    {
        return new MyTabLayoutAppearanceTracker(this);
    }
}

public class MyTabLayoutAppearanceTracker : ShellTabLayoutAppearanceTracker
{
    public MyTabLayoutAppearanceTracker(IShellContext shellContext) : base(shellContext)
    {
    }
    public override void SetAppearance(TabLayout tabLayout, ShellAppearance appearance)
    {
        base.SetAppearance(tabLayout, appearance);

        tabLayout.TabMode = TabLayout.ModeFixed;
        tabLayout.TabGravity = TabLayout.GravityFill;
    }
}
```

For **iOS**:

Create the class: CustomShellRenderer.cs under **Platform/iOS**:

```
   public class CustomShellRenderer : ShellRenderer
   {

       protected override IShellSectionRenderer CreateShellSectionRenderer(ShellSection shellSection)
       {
           var shellSectionRenderer = new CustomShellSectionRenderer(this);
           return shellSectionRenderer;
       }
   }

   public class CustomShellSectionRenderer : ShellSectionRenderer
   {

       public CustomShellSectionRenderer(IShellContext context) : base(context)
       { }

       protected override IShellSectionRootRenderer CreateShellSectionRootRenderer(ShellSection shellSection, IShellContext shellContext)
       {
           var renderer = new CustomShellSectionRootRenderer(shellSection, shellContext);

           return renderer;
       }
   }

   public class CustomShellSectionRootRenderer : ShellSectionRootRenderer
   {
       public CustomShellSectionRootRenderer(ShellSection section, IShellContext context) : base(section, context)
       { }

       protected override IShellSectionRootHeader CreateShellSectionRootHeader(IShellContext shellContext)
       {
           var renderer = new CustomShellSectionRootHeader(shellContext);
           return renderer;
       }
   }

   public class CustomShellSectionRootHeader : ShellSectionRootHeader
   {
       public CustomShellSectionRootHeader(IShellContext context) : base(context)
       {

       }

       public override UICollectionViewCell GetCell(UICollectionView collectionView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
       {
           var cell = base.GetCell(collectionView, indexPath) as ShellSectionHeaderCell;

           var layout = new UICollectionViewFlowLayout();
           layout.MinimumInteritemSpacing = UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Size.Width / 5;
           layout.SectionInset = new UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 10, bottom: 0, right:0);
           layout.ItemSize = new SizeF(120, 50);
           layout.ScrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirection.Horizontal;

           collectionView.CollectionViewLayout = layout;

           return cell;
       }
   }

   public class CustomUICollectionViewFlowLayout : UICollectionViewFlowLayout
   {
       public override UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes[] LayoutAttributesForElementsInRect(CGRect rect)
       {
           return base.LayoutAttributesForElementsInRect(rect);

       }

   }
```

Then, register the handlers in the `MauiProgram.cs`:

```
.ConfigureMauiHandlers(handlers => {

#if ANDROID        
                        handlers.AddHandler(typeof(Shell),typeof(CustomShellRenderer));

# elif IOS
                          handlers.AddHandler(typeof(Shell),typeof(CustomShellRenderer));
#endif
                    });
```

**Android:**

[image]

**iOS:**

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iyPUQ.png]